# Запуск socket.io на сервере. Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, сервер

> Ошибка - Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

всё в одной папке...

Код Html файла

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO net</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Код JS file'a

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);


app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: Вот этот код JS файла это содержимое того `index.js`, что вы подключаете в HTML коде?

Comment: Так вы index.js в браузере запускаете что-ли? Конечно в браузере нет require.

Comment: Вы немного напутали. Ваш JS-файл должен выполняться на сервере c node. index.js для вашей страницы должен быть другим

Answer (score 1):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Такая ошибка значит, что вы пробуете выполнить в браузере код, предназначенный для nodejs.

1. Откройте терминал
2. Перейдите в директорию вашего JS файла
3. Выполните `node filename.js`